# How to identify the last row in the result set postgres?

Tags: postgresql, go

I am using Postgres 9.5 with and using golang library lib/pq to interact with database. I execute a select query which returns multiple rows and then I iterate using `for rows.Next()` Is there anyway I ca stop before the lat record. I want to print something else on console if its the last record. Something like the following:

```
for rows.Next() {

    var id string
    err = rows.Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error in rows.Scan: %s\n", err)
    }

    if (row is not last) {
        fmt.Println(id + "I am not last")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(id + "I am last")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can impliment something like a do while loop in go.

```
notLast := rows.Next()
for notLast {
    //... rows.Scan
    notLast = rows.next()
    if notLast {
        fmt.Println(id + "I am not last")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(id + "I am last")
    }
}
```